# Vaadin UI not updating while changing UI components from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, vaadin

I've got the following code snippet in a normal private function, which is called from another method in the same class (the class is called `AdministrationComponent` which `extends CustomComponent`). This component is added to a `TabBarView`. My problem is, that the three labels you can see in the code are not updated.

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        while (true)
        {
          try
          {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          Runnable uiRunnable = () -> {
            DSCXPSStatusInformation dsi = xpsService.getDSCXPSStatusInformation();

            totalSpaceLabel.setValue(String.valueOf(dsi.getTotalSpaceInMB()) + " MB");
            spaceLeftLabel.setValue(String.valueOf(dscxpsStatusInformation.getLeftSpaceInMB()) + " MB");
            uptimeLabel.setValue(String.valueOf(dscxpsStatusInformation.getUptimeInSec()) + " sec");
          };

          UI.getCurrent().access(uiRunnable);
          UI.getCurrent().push();
        }
      }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the section about Push in the [book of vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html)

You need to enable push, so the webserver can inform the webbrowser about changes in the UI.

Comment: It is activated: @Push (PushMode.MANUAL)

Comment: Are the labels updated when the next user interaction happens?

Comment: They are just updated if I leave the TabSheet and visit it again, cause then it is rebuild. If I just switch between the different Tabs, nothing happens.

Comment: I wonder if the `UI.getCurrent().push()`is fired too fast, have you tried to put the push inside the uiRunnable block? (Have you tryed with Push auto?)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer: I am using `dscxpsStatusInformation` instead of `dsi`. I don't know why there is no error in eclipse. I don't have `dscxpsStatusInformation` anywhere in this class.